# How to connect Oracle Db to Windows CE Apps in VS 2008 C# or Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am creating a windows CE apps for stock taking, i don't know how to create it, i need to connect my main database server(oracle 12.1.2), i am using local db as sqlce, Any one can tell what to do??

This code is using on button click :

```
string oradb = "User Id= *****;Password=**********;Data Source=ORCL;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
try {
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME 
                           FROM PDTABD.XXADNPM_BARCODE_DELIVERY_DTL";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read()) {
        var myString = dr.GetString(0);
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Name is " + myString);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

conn.Close();   
conn.Dispose();
```

This code is running on WPF normal section, but in WIN CE app it doesn't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this tutorial from Oracle?
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/database-mobile-server/wince-tutorial-10-3-129778.pdf

Comment: This tutorial is helpful in this case, But in my case i changed the method to web service, So its run smoothly. Any way thanks a lot